# login fails after upgrade ? How to reset password

Tags: upgrade, login, password

I have just done an upgrade after receiving a notification.
I then went to command line F3 but the login failed.
Going back to normal with F1 put up the login page with the comment "Not Listed". Also the password failed.

How do I reset user name and password without reinstalling ?
I cannot be sure that the upgrade caused the problem because I had not used the command facility for a few weeks and the problem may have occurred earlier without my detecting it.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what OS/product/release you're asking about, including any release details. What type of update was it? package update? kernel update? *release-upgrade*? etc.  Is this a desktop system you're asking about? a server system?  Please provide OS/product/release details and clues as to what upgrade you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was Ubuntu 20.04 and the update was about Chrome mainly as far as I can tell. It is a desktop and not networked.

Comment: "*the update was about Chrome mainly as far as I can tell*" Review your logs in /var/log/apt, which lists *exactly* what was upgraded, and exactly what errors you encountered (if any) during that upgrade. Correlation with an upgrade is not definite proof of a cause, so also check your /var/log/syslog and journal for other errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot open log files; "permission denied"

Comment: I was able to open syslog ok but it only had todays log. The presumably earlier logs ending .7.gz etc were permission denied. As I cannot change permissions without using sudo etc there seems to be no solution. Knowing what caused the problem will not solve the problem. I need to reset my username and password.